# How to make iPad auto-scale large-width element which also has overflow: scroll to full displayed?

Tags: css

At first, I'm not developing a responsive design page. So I didn't add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Here is my codes:

**CSS:**

```
<style>
section {
    width: 1250px;
    height: 800px;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/1250x800) no-repeat 50% top;
}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</div>
```

When visit these with iPad, `<section>`s are auto-scaled to fit the iPad screen. You do not need to scroll horizontally to watch the full images. This is exactly what I want.

However, if I add `overflow` to the `.container`, iPad don't auto-scale the page anymore:

```
.container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I'm actually going to implement some scroll effect on iPad. As iPad will not fire the "scroll" event of "window" before the scroll action stops, I have to scroll the content of page in a large `overflow-y: scroll;` element.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I just need iPad auto scale down to display the full-width, no need to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'll want to start setting `height:100%;` on your containers. If you set your container height to 100%, it will always take the height of whatever screen it's on. Then, setting `section` heights to 100% will make them fill in that same space always at 100% of your screen size. This will orient the images to 100% but still let you scroll